# wp-cron.php is triggered, but scheduled post is not published

Tags: wp-cron

I am new to wordpress.  My site had been posting scheduled posts, but it seems to stopped due to *no traffic*.  So I disabled wp default cron, and setup a cron job via cPanel.

via command
`wget -q -O - http://1pm.today/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

And 
`usr/bin/curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron http://1pm.today/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

But running wp-cron.php like this doesn't seem to trigger scheduled post.

I even tried to trigger cron job from a browser (not sure if it is the right way)
`http://1pm.today/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`

But none of this trigger publish any scheduled post.  Should cron job like this suppose to publish scheduled post?  If so, any advice to debug this would be greatly appreciated, I will try to work with the tech support as the site is on a shared host.

I have added echo statement in wp-cron.php

```
function _get_cron_lock() {
    global $wpdb;

    $value = 0;
    if ( wp_using_ext_object_cache() ) {
        /*
         * Skip local cache and force re-fetch of doing_cron transient
         * in case another process updated the cache.
         */
        $value = wp_cache_get( 'doing_cron', 'transient', true );
    } else {
        $row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name = %s LIMIT 1", '_transient_doing_cron' ) );
        if ( is_object( $row ) )
            $value = $row->option_value;
    }

    return $value;
}

if ( false === $crons = _get_cron_array() )
    die();

$keys = array_keys( $crons );
$gmt_time = microtime( true );
echo "$keys[0] > $gmt_time";
if ( isset($keys[0]) && $keys[0] > $gmt_time )
    die();

echo ":6c";
// The cron lock: a unix timestamp from when the cron was spawned.
$doing_cron_transient = get_transient( 'doing_cron' );
echo "7";
```

And the output is

```
1465529020 > 1465525264.31 without reaching ":6c"
```

So it `die()`s because of

```
if ( isset($keys[0]) && $keys[0] > $gmt_time )

1465529020 > 1465525264.31
```

May I ask where `$keys[0]` came from?

I am guessing the `$key[0]` is a timestamp of the first cron job and `$gmt_time` is the current time, and if `$key[0]` is in the future and it should abort.

I already have a lot of "miss scheduled" post, so I am trying to better understand `_get_cron_array()` but I don't get what's going on in `wp-includes/cron.php.

It seems that `_get_cron_array()` has something to do with *cron* in `wp_options`

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_options`
WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%cron%'
```

At this point, I am even more confused, as I can't figure out how a scheduled post is linked to the cron job.

Comment: Have you checked your server time (cli) and you actual application time?

Answer (score 1):

The _get_cron_array() function gets the 'cron' option out of the database. The cron option contains an array consisting of a series of unix-timestamps and action hooks.

So, when the timestamp is reached, then the action hook is called.

The timestamp of 1465529020 is the equivalent of June 10th, 2016, at 3:23am in UTC time.

The timestamp of 1465525264 is the equivalent of June 10th, 2016, at 2:21am in UTC time.

So, basically, that action was scheduled to run 1 hour and 2 minutes later. Which is why wp-cron didn't run it. It wasn't time yet.

Scheduling a post to publish at a specific time creates an entry in the cron array with the time to publish it as the key, and the action that it fires to publish it as the value. When the time is reached, the action hook gets fired, and the post gets published. That's how wp-cron.php works.